# Fail2ban, jail.conf not exist

Tags: linux, fail2ban

I installed `Fail2ban` to my debian, but I haven't `jail.conf` file in `/etc/fail2ban/`.

I have only:

```
action.d, filter.d
```

Where can I find `jail.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

That file is contained in the `fail2ban` package as reported in the [list of files](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/fail2ban/filelist) or by running:

```
# apt-file list fail2ban
```

or

```
# apt-file search jail.conf
```

If it's not there, you can try reinstalling the package:

```
# aptitude reinstall fail2ban
```

or

```
# apt-get install --reinstall fail2ban
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also find those missing files directly on the source of fail2ban here : https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban

You'll find the files in config folder (https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/tree/0.11/config)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/264822)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek If the question is "where can I find this file" and the answer is "in the source repository", linking to it seems like the only sane thing to do

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I disagree. Just finding the file is only the tip of the iceberg, and certainly not the true problem (just copying arbitrary files from a repository to its own system and hoping that everything works without messing package management is certainly not a practice for sane sysadmin). dawud's answer seems far more on the topic for me. Also the "where" could as well mean "where on my host" in which case any remote link is useless... (the question is poor, and not really useful to reply 3 years later)